# Multiple classes in ngClass

Tags: angular, ng-class

I'm trying to add multiple values in *ngClass, what used to work on previous alpha releases and doesn't seem to work now on angular2 beta:

```
<i *ngClass="['fa','fa-star']"></i>
```

It produces an error:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined in
>   [['fa','fa-star'] in PostView@30:27]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use square brackets to create property binding. See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wYmZvsCzhOErNzdAEKNT?p=preview)

```html
<i [ngClass]="['fa','fa-star']"></i>
```

Comment: How do you change these classes dynamically if you're providing the array in your template?

Comment: @Zyzle I would create some variable for this array and change it from my component (for example `[ngClass]="myDynamicArray"`).

Comment: I would update the answer then, as I pointed out, the original example is no different from simply doing `class="fa fa-star"` in the template

Comment: @Zyzle I don't think there is a need for this. The problem was about using of incorrect syntax for property binding. And you've already specified about `class="fa fa-star"` in your answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can also build a string containing several classes.

In this case *additionalClass* is an @Input var containing the classname and *active* is a boolean that sets the active class

```
<div [ngClass]="(additionalClass + ' ' + (active ? 'active' : ''))"></div>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you aren't going to be changing these classes dynamically then using `ngClass` is overkill. You can simply use `class="fa fa-star"` in your template.

`ngClass` should be used when you when you want to switch these on and off dynamically. There's an example in the docs:

Your component would have a method:

```
setClasses() {
  return {
    saveable: this.canSave,      // true
    modified: !this.isUnchanged, // false
    special: this.isSpecial,     // true
  }
}
```

then use `ngClass` in your template like so:

```
<div [ngClass]="setClasses()">This div is saveable and special</div>
```

Comment: I was changing them dynamically, But your solution is really interesting.

Comment: Ok, but how do you plan on changing them if you've hard coded the array into ngClass?

Comment: I simplified the example in question. In my real case I use dynamic classes returned from a component method.

Comment: In your solution `setClasses()` will be called on every change detection, resulting in creating a new object every time. I would strongly recommend against this. Best would be to just define the object directly in the view template: `[ngClass]="{ saveable: this.canSave, modified: !this.isUnchanged, special: this.isSpecial }"`. See also [one of many blogposts](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496) on this topic.