# Add Array to ngclass angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to add an array of classes to a row. my issue is that is duplicating the row. so my question is how can i loop though a arrow inside `[ngClass]`

my code that doesn't work.

**.ts**

```
@Input() rowClasses = ['someClass1', 'someClass2']
```

**html**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>some head</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr class="striped-row" *ngFor="class of rowClasses" [ngClass]="class"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the for-loop you just have to directly assign your array to ngClass 
Example :

```
[ngClass]="rowClasses"
```

or

```
[ngClass]="['someClass1', 'someClass2']"
```

[useful answere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34518801/3476801) and
[documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html)

Comment: Accept the answer , to help others , if you think its correct.

Comment: @JT1979 first accept the answer, it will make +2 points(you will reach to 15 pts), thereafter you can upvote I guess.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`class` property should not wrap your `class` with `{}`, just provide `class` to `[ngClass]` property binding. In that case you could do `[ngClass]="class"`</strike>

Your question seems unclear that doesn't clearly stating where you wanted to apply class `on each row`/`class for different row`

If that classes should be display on single row then just pass `rowClasses` to [ngClass] directive

```
[ngClass]="rowClasses"
```

Comment: @JT1979 check updated answer, It should work.. Initailly question wasn't stating problem correctly..

Comment: JT1979 does mine answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You are looping on `tr` so you are duplicating html. You don't need to loop on css classes

```
[ngClass]="rowClasses" //<-- assuming `rowClasses` is an array
```

**Example Usage:**
`<some-element [ngClass]="['first', 'second']">...</some-element>`

check the documentation for other ways to add classes
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html